# Remove right and bottom margin on infowindows

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, infowindow

I'm playing around with the google InfoWindow.

And almost everything is perfect. I'm Just missing something on the windows.

I always have a right and bottom white space.

I don't mind that much for the bottom one but I'd like to get rid of the right one.

Any idea how to do that ?

[image: example]

**EDIT, here is the code:**

```
<div class="gm-style-iw" style="position: absolute; left: 12px; top: 9px; overflow: auto; width: 352px; height: 290px;">
  <div class="" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div class="infoBox">
      <div style="max-width: 352px; padding: 0px;">
        <div id="info-map-element"> 
          <div class="street"> 
            <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=360x190&amp;location=37.7831059,-122.4446528&amp;fov=90&amp;heading=235&amp;pitch=10&amp;sensor=false" alt=""> 
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="title"> Customer History<br> 123 Foo Av, San Francisco, CA 12345</div>       
          </div>
          <div class="wrap clearfix"> 
            <div class="item  clearfix">
              <small>2013-09-11</small>
              <p>This is the a test of customer history purchases.</p>
                <div class="row clearfix">
                  <div class="col-lg-5"> Cost Estimate <span>$11000</span></div>
                <div class="col-lg-7"> Purchase No. <span>123456789</span></div>
            </div> 
            <div class="row clearfix">
              <div class="col-lg-12"> Sell by <a href="">My Online seller dot com</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


#map_newsfeed .gm-style-iw {
    width: 352px!important;
    height: auto!important;
    left: 0!important;
    font-size: 15px!important;
    font-weight: normal!important;
    top: 0!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#map_newsfeed .gm-style-iw > div {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}.gm-style .gm-style-iw, .gm-style .gm-style-iw a, .gm-style .gm-style-iw span, .gm-style .gm-style-iw label, .gm-style .gm-style-iw div {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}#info-map-element .row > div {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
#info-map-element .shadow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -35px 75px rgba(0,0,0,0.95) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -35px 75px rgba(0,0,0,0.95) inset;
    position: absolute;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 1;
}
#map .gm-style {
    font-family: inherit;
}#info-map-element .pagination {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}
.infoBox > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 25px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
#info-map-element .pointer {
    width:23px;
    height:19px;
    top: 99%;
    left: 41%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background: transparent url('http://d3flf7kkefqaeh.cloudfront.net/_assets/3/pointer_down.png'); 
}#info-map-element .wrap {
    padding: 0;
}
#info-map-element .wrap .item:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ececec;
}
#info-map-element .wrap .item {
    padding: 10px;
}#legend strong {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    display: block;
}
```

EDTI #2:
So I can change the dom the way I want it with Jquery. Those 3 lines work"

```
$(".gm-style-iw").next("div").css("right", '52px');
$(".gm-style-iw").prev("div").children().last().css("width", '351px');
$($(".gm-style-iw").prev("div").children()[1]).css("width", '351px');
```

But for some reason only the first line get executed.

Comment: You can simply override the `css` of the `infoWindow`.  Inspect those elements using `dev tools of browsers(F12)`, take your own time and come back.

Comment: Paste your html from the infobox.

Comment: I think the right margin is to clear the "close button".

Comment: Added the CSS+html of the infowindow. In the source it says infobox for the CSS but it's a infowindows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first remove the infowindow background & shadow, then apply your own css.

**JS part**

```
/*
 * The google.maps.event.addListener() event waits for
 * the creation of the infowindow HTML structure 'domready'
 * and before the opening of the infowindow defined styles
 * are applied.
 */
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

   // Reference to the DIV which receives the contents of the infowindow using jQuery
   var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

   /* The DIV we want to change is above the .gm-style-iw DIV.
    * So, we use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
    * and took advantage of the existing reference to .gm-style-iw for the previous DIV with .prev().
    */
   var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

   // Remove the background shadow DIV
   iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

   // Remove the white background DIV
   iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

});
```

**CSS part (example)**

```
.gm-style-iw {
   width: 350px !important;
   top: 0 !important;
   left: 0 !important;
   background-color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
   border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
   border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
```

[Source](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html)

Answer (score 11):

The padding is caused by the scroll applied to the `.gm-style-iw-d` div, this would remove it but be careful and make sure all your content fits inside the max width and height of the info window cause otherwise it will be hidden.

```
.gm-style-iw-d {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution! Also add this to remove the infowindow padding:
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c {
    padding: 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still looking for solution. Angular 8, helped the code below to remove the paddings and hide the close button for agm-info-window.
Basically, `overflow: scroll` in `.gm-style-iw-d` element creates that space.

```
/* hide close button in info-window */
::ng-deep button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* clear the paddings  */
::ng-deep .gm-style .gm-style-iw-c {
  padding: 0;
}

/* remove the white space */
::ng-deep .gm-style-iw .gm-style-iw-d {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should stop to try fix height/width and set it auto. 
Try to change this line:

```
<div class="gm-style-iw" style="position: absolute; left: 12px; top: 9px; overflow: auto; width: 352px; height: 290px;">
```

To this:

```
<div class="gm-style-iw" style="position: absolute; left: 12px; top: 9px; overflow: auto; width: auto; height: auto;">
```

In the Css change:

```
#map_newsfeed .gm-style-iw {
  width: 352px!important;
  height: auto!important;
  left: 0!important;
  font-size: 15px!important;
  font-weight: normal!important;
  top: 0!important;
  overflow: hidden!important;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

To:

```
#map_newsfeed .gm-style-iw {
  width: auto!important;
  height: auto!important;
  left: 0!important;
  font-size: 15px!important;
  font-weight: normal!important;
  top: 0!important;
  overflow: hidden!important;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

It should solve your problem, if not, please show the full code (html/css).

Comment: HI @bl0b  Did you get any answer on that? I am looking for the same thing. Thanks