# Removing X from infowindow with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using google maps and the problem is that we have by default a margin right with an "x". The only customization that I need is to remove this margin and "x" and make this card to be closed when is clicked outside.

Obs: I'm using the gem gmaps4rails.

Obs 2: I have the same issue that was asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542870/remove-right-and-bottom-margin-on-infowindows) post and any of the answers solved to me. Maybe the code was updated in 2017 or the gem has a particular way to make it? This is his picture:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I pointed this out but I guess that because I'm using gmaps4rails and/or it is 3 years ago the code didn't solve my problem...

Comment: OK, yes, sorry, my fault. I remove the flag.